# Eigenvectors of matrix that is triangular

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&3\\0&1&-2\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix}.$$

And obtained the eigenvalues $\{1, 2, 3\}$.

For $\lambda = 2$, I get this matrix after row reduction: $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Here is what I tried: 
$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}y = 0\\
z = 0\end{array}\right.$$

but what now? Aren't I supposed to express it with a free variable, $x$ ? But how can I if its all $0$ ?

I successfully obtained the vector for eigenvalue $\lambda= 3$.

Comment: The general solution for the last system is $(x,0,0)$. Put, for example, $x=1$ and you'll get an eigenvector.

Comment: @user35603 Thanks! but why x = 1? i mean, why not x = 0 or x = -1? I thought there was *one* corresponding eigen vector for an eigen value?

Comment: $x=-1$ can be; since you need non-zero vector; usually (for matrix over $\mathbb{R}$) there are infinitely many corresponding eigenvectors (if they are exist)

Comment: $x=0$ is not good, since an eigenvector is not allowed to be (entirely) zero. Any other value of $x$ is OK, since nonzero scalar multiples of an eigenvector are eigenvectors (for the same eigenvalue) just as well. That is why one talks about an _eigenspace_ associated to each eigenvalue. (But note that although the zero vector is in the eigenspace, it is not an eigenvector.) If you thought there was only one eigenvector per eigenvalue, this is entirely wrong; it is _never_ true (over the real or complex numbers, or indeed almost any field). And eigenspaces may even have dimension${}>1$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks for the additional info. Perhaps in lectures and tutorials they say something like "find the corresponding eigen vector" so I thought that there was only one. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, how come you found **the** eigenvalue for $\lambda=3$? You should have got (effectively) two (homogeneous linear) equations for three coordinates there as well, which system does not have a _unique_ solution either.

Comment: Yes I have got 2 homogeneous linear equations. But my brain could work through it as x - 2z = 0 and y + z = 0. [z(free variable) is present in the equations !!! like, x = 2z, y = -z, z = z)-but this one, x(free variable) is not present in my equations; y + z = 0 and z = 0...so I did not know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

For triangular matrices as  $ A=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 3  \\  0 & 1 & -2  \\      0 & 0 & 3\end{bmatrix} $

the equation $Av=\lambda v$ can be presented as a set of equations

$\left \{ \begin{array}{c}2x+y+3z = \lambda x \\ 
  y-2z=\lambda y \\ 3z=\lambda z \end{array} \right.$

which is relatively easy to solve if we start from $z$ from the third equation , next $y$ from the second one  and $x$ from the first one (always consider possible zero and non-zero value - first calculated non-zero value can be taken arbitrarily as for example equal to $1$).

Comment: Interesting for eigenvectors of triangular matrix is fact the they can compose matrix which is also ... triangular.

Answer (score 0):

$(A - \lambda I)v = 0\\
(A - 2 I)v = 0\\
\begin {bmatrix}0&1&3\\0&-1&-2\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}v = 0\\
v = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

On to the others

$(A -  I)v = 0\\
\begin {bmatrix}1&1&3\\0&0&-2\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}v = 0\\
v = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

$(A -  3I)v = 0\\
\begin {bmatrix}-1&1&3\\0&-2&-2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}v = 0\\
v = \begin{bmatrix} 2\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$